# Возможно ли удалить элементы коллекции из другой коллекции?

Tags: c#

Возможно ли метод ClearProcessedSprites сделать одной строкой через лямбду и избавиться от него?

```
    List<SpriteModel> m_spritesKit;

    List<SpriteModel> m_processedSprites;

    private void ClearProcessedSprites()
    {
        List<SpriteModel> spriteList = new List<SpriteModel>();

        foreach (var value in m_spritesKit)
        {
            if (!m_processedSprites.Contains(value))
            {
                spriteList.Add(value);
            }
        }

        m_spritesKit = spriteList;

    }
}
```

Comment: `m_spritesKit.Where(x=>!m_processedSprites.Contains(x));`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, так удобнее

Comment: В ответ тогда пишите то, что получилось у вас.

Comment: Ему у `SpriteModel` еще `IEquatable` - определить придется. Иначе будет работать только если они равны по ссылке.